# Does netstat -l include anything that netstat -a does not have?

Tags: command-line, netstat

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, but I believe my question applies to many distros, such as Debian, CentOS, and Red Hat.

The manpage for `netstat -l` is:

```
Show only listening sockets.  (These are omitted by default.)
```

and `netstat -a` is:

```
Show both listening and non-listening sockets.  With the  -- 
interfaces option, show interfaces that are not up
```

Does the output of `netstat -a` include the output of `nestat -l`? It seems like so in the manpage but many websites talk about `netstat -plantu` so I am wondering if `netstat -l` covers something that `netstat -a` does not.

Comment: Which OS/distro/version ? Better add this to your original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the 2nd part of your question, `netstat -plantu` will show you only tcp and udp info, that is network connections established and listening ports. `netstat -a` will show you unix sockets also. That's lots of info, it's better to target what you need on the output.

If you run a recent distro, you can use `ss` instead of `netstat`. It's a modern alternative, takes the same parametres.

I usually type `ss -tulp` (same as `netstat -tulp`) to check all listening ports on my servers/PCs plus the processes which opened the ports; the possible incoming traffic will be addressed on this ports. To check the current connections and processes, `ss -tuap`. For `-p` you need root/sudo permissions, in order to view processes of all users.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the output of `netstat -a` include the output of `nestat -l`

Yes, `-a` stands for all (listening and non-listening sockets).